# Interested in a "more fundamental" proof for basic properties of the logical connectives

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, foundations

Starting with the classical propositional logic, is there a rather canonical way to prove that $$p\wedge q=q\wedge p$$ for the commutativity of the conjunction and analogously for the other properties and connectives, other than using truth tables, visualizing with Venn diagrams akin [Wikipedia's approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction), or verbal philosophical reasoning?

Put it other way, can we well-define the connectives from a deeper foundation than that?

For example, in set theory, we define a union of the two sets $A$, $B$ as $$A\cap B:=\{x\,|\,x\in A\wedge x\in B\}$$
to then move on and prove that $\cap$ is commutative. By doing so we simply delegate the proof to the very propositional (or whichever) logic we defined the operator with $$A\cap B\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\{x\,|\,x\in A\wedge x\in B\}\overset{\mathrm{com}}{=}\{x\,|\,x\in B\wedge x\in A\}\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}B\cap A.\square$$

Comment: If I have guessed your "more fundamental" correctly, then any such proof will rely mostly on the definitions of elements involved. What is your definition of "$\land$" (and other relevant notions)?

Comment: Since the inputs are *very* finite, it wouldn't surprise me that the $\wedge$ operator's definition is simply its truth table, and that there's no proof, or need for proof, behind that.

Comment: Conjunction is defined as a function $\wedge: \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \to \{0,1\}$, so basically yes it is defined by its truth table. A proof of commutativity will depend on what axioms you choose.

Comment: @dtldarek: I'm afraid I don't know in what way there is a difference between the elements involved. I'm referring to propositional sentences, without any predicates, just the fundamentals of classical logic, non-modal. This has made me very curious, what other elements are there? I define $\wedge$ as $true$ only if both operands are $true$, $\vee$ is $false$ only if both are $false$.

Comment: @zneak: what other inputs are feasible? Or how else can one define the conjunction?

Comment: @KevinDriscoll: I'm aware there is a difference between the connectives per se and the truth-functional interpretation of them, as between the material conditional (implication) which is the connective and the logical consequence for the syntactic consequence in proof theory and the entailment in model theory. But I can't tell that difference. So if I assume right, there must be some notional deviation of a truth-functional from the rather philosophical (truth tables) definition. Other than that the Cartesian product, if defined as $\{(a,b)|a\in\{0,1\}\wedge b\in\{0,1\}\}$ presumes $\wedge$.

Comment: @user102118, there are only 4 possible input combinations to the $\wedge$ operator, so it's trivial to demonstrate that $p \wedge q = q \wedge p$: you only have to compare entries with each other and you're done. There exists no counter-example to prove this is false, therefore it must be true.

Comment: @user102118 Sorry, I'm not really sure what you're asking. If we have a function, all we have to do is specify what it does to each element in its domain. In a total formalization of propositional logic this is all there is. For many-valued logics the domain becomes larger. Could you expand more on what else you think there ought to be?

Comment: @zneak: Do you mean $(t,t),(t,f),(f,t),(f,f)$? Your first comment subtly implies there would be some other way to define the conjunction, I'm referring to "wouldn't surprise me." Did you mean there's some other way to define it? Or am I just misinterpreting?

Comment: @KevinDriscoll: I haven't studied functions or logic thoroughly yet, I'm sorry I can't exactly explain my idea. But what's striking is how we define a function. From what I've seen so far, it's a mapping with an "assignment rule," or, what I at that point prefer, a tuple (I can imagine that there are many more definitions). I can't speak of the "assignment rule" as it needs to be defined as something I can't speak of right now. But a tuple is an ordered set which we define with predicates using actually the predefined conjunction of the propositional logic. I mean something must go first.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll: I've got a good book here on Logic - Rautenberg, Introduction to Logic (Springer). He also suggests your way of formalization via truth functions but not from the outset. I do understand that introducing a Boolean algebra to get a calculus makes sense. But it doesn't appear to be fundamental to the notion of a conjunction. To me, it appears as rather a product of the conjunction, just as the notion of a function, or a mapping.

Comment: @user102118 Oh, you seem to be saying that the definition I gave is circular because it presumes conjunction. This seems to confuse the object logical language with its meta-language. The definition of the connectives occurs in the meta-language. So, yes, we have to have a mathematical meta-language first, which in full would require a completely rigorous and consistent set theory. But this is rather impractical, we can't wait for a full set theory before we do logic.

Comment: For example, $\{0,1\}$ is not an object in our logical language. So it makes no sense to try and say that this definition exists in the object language. It has to be in the meta-language. So, we must take some things in the meta-language as given and then we can define the logical connectives. We might say, suppose you have the purely formal rules $$\{0,0\}\to 0, \{0,1\} \to 0, \{1,0\} \to 0, \{1,1\} \to 1,$$ then, in the object language, call this set of rules $\wedge$, what else follows? Whether these rules are well-defined etc. is a meta-logical question, not a logical one.

Comment: "I define $\land$ as $\mathtt{true}$ only if both operands are $\mathtt{true}$ [and $\mathtt{false}$ otherwise]." Given such definition, the proof of commutativity lies in the fact that your meta-language phrase "only if both operands are" does not take the order of operands into account. Using that particular definition, I guess there isn't any more fundamental approach. You could try to use meta-meta-level language, but the again you wouldn't be satisfied, and go to use meta-meta-meta language and so on, ad infinitum. I think that in base cases, the truth table is the best there is.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll: you're right, I'm mixing up the both layers. Please correct if I paraphrase wrongly. So, absent the metalanguage-set theory, we for the time being assume that which we would otherwise derive from it to the scope that hasn't been proved. Would that set of rules of the metalanguage be considered the set of axioms upon which the object language depends? And which part of the truth function is in the metalanguage--only the intrinsics of the Cartesian product or its entirety? I've encountered so far axiomatic object languages, e.g., the ZFC, and minimalistic like $(\neg,\wedge)$.

Comment: @user102118 It's a bit worse than what you suggest, because thanks to Godel we know that there is no consistency proof of our meta-language, but yes. I wouldn't consider the meta-language rules as part of the axioms. We use the meta-language to define and discuss the object language. Axioms exist in the object language. The reason I wouldn't consider the meta-language rules as axioms is that they are not sufficient to derive theorems. Once we have defined connectives, we still need some additional rules (modus ponens, etc.) to actually conclude anything.

Comment: Axioms are the minimal things we wish to assume for our system. The meta-language rules are too weak to fit this criterion. As far as I remember, the entirety of the definition of the connectives, variables, constants, etc is in the meta-language. The ONLY things in the object language are well-formed formulas, which use ONLY '$\wedge$,' '$\rightarrow$,' 'p,' 'q,' '(,' etc etc

Comment: @dtldarek: this is a very good point, totally agree. Thank you! I guess what you, user43208, and KevinDriscoll have made clear to me, is that I seem to be after some non-arbitrarity in logic, subconsciously. Which, as KevinDriscoll puts referring to the set theory of the metalanguage isn't there.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll: This is a clear distinction, thanks for pointing this out. Could you please also expand on this: "$\{0,1\}$ is not an object in our logical language. ... It has to be in the meta-language."? Is that set part of the metalanguage if we define a truth function as part of the metalanguage? And how would a syntactically equivalent set in the ZFC set theory relate to the object language? That is, is there a hierarchy like metalanguage->object language->formal systems/concepts (derivations of the object-language axioms)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this will satisfy you, but a categorically-minded way to characterize meets $a \wedge b$ and joins $a \vee b$ is via universal properties:

$$x \leq a \wedge b \;\;\; \text{iff}\;\;\; x \leq a,\; x \leq b$$

$$a \vee b \leq x\;\;\; \text{iff}\;\;\; a \leq x,\; b \leq x$$

for any $x$. These are general definitions in the theory of posets or preorders, but for propositions, we can think of $\leq$ as denoting the entailment relation. The pair of entailments on the right (for each of $\wedge, \vee$) simply means both are asserted.

In that case, one can prove $a \wedge b = b \wedge a$. For, we have

$$x \leq a \wedge b\;\;\; \text{iff}\;\;\; x \leq a, x \leq b\;\;\; \text{iff}\;\;\; x \leq b \wedge a.$$

Now, since $a \wedge b \leq a \wedge b$, we can put $x = a \wedge b$ and reason forward to conclude $a \wedge b \leq b \wedge a$. Similarly, putting $x = b \wedge a$ and reasoning backward, we conclude $b \wedge a \leq a \wedge b$. Thus, if we take propositions to be equal if they entail one another (i.e., if we assume the antisymmetry axiom for posets), we derive $a \wedge b = b \wedge a$. Similarly we can prove $a \vee b = b \vee a$.

A similar "universality argument" can be used to prove that $\wedge, \vee$ are associative, idempotent, etc.

Once we have universal characterizations for $\wedge, \vee$, we can add a third that characterizes negation

$$a \wedge b \leq c\;\;\; \text{iff}\;\;\; a \leq (\neg b) \vee c$$

and in this way we get classical propositional logic (more exactly, we'd add in two more to characterize the top element $\top$ ("true") and $\bot$ ("false")).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To clarify, would you then lay category theory as the sublayer to propositional logic? And in the ordering relation in your first paragraph, wouldn't we presume some sort of "conjunction" to already exist when we demand $x\le a,x<\le b" at the position of the comma to then flip the atoms and so delegate the proof of commutativity to that very comma in your third paragraph? I've just started out in math and haven't read anything on category theory but have been studying mathematical logic somewhat, I may just be misunderstanding your answer.

Comment: It might seem controversial to some to say this, but in some sense I do see the rules of inference in logic as admitting a more conceptual understanding rooted in adjoint functors (a la Lawvere), although it would take some time to fully elaborate this so as not to be misunderstood. Your second question is also good; however, I think of the order of the formulas as an artifact of the linearity of symbols typed on paper; it might help to intuitively imagine these assertions rather as "free floating" in space. I.e., no order is implied; their juxtaposition simply says "both are true".

Comment: I've noticed a rise in popularity or, rather, interest in, category theory over the past couple of years, while I was getting more and more involved in some sort of self-study after work. I surely will take lectures in category theory near the end of BSc. Thank you for bringing up this concept. Regarding the second question, isn't it the same with the conjunction? As I understand, category-theoretically there is no notion of order for the two relations $x≤a,x≤b$ outside them, as if they are floating in space. Then commutativity is thus inherent. Why do we go the path of a proof in logic?

Comment: When you say 'conjunction', there is the question of whether you mean a formal conjunction (a syntactic construction), or conjunction on the meta-level of a human user who understands what 'both' or 'and' means (or a computer program with an arrangement of gates that faithfully reflects our use of 'and'). I understand the rules of inference (as presented by the universal characterization) as interfacing between the linguistic/formal $\wedge$ and an external manipulation as performed by electrons passing through gates or neurons, at an extra-linguistic meta-level, if I may put it so crudely.

Comment: So we are giving a formal derivation of $a \wedge b = b \wedge a$, but this does rely ultimately on some external human or computer representation. Am I making sense to you? :-)

Comment: Of course does it make sense to me, absolutely. I'm still mixing up the metalanguage and the formal language of logic. Prof Schwichtenberg (LMU Munich) puts this very well in his lecture materials on natural deduction which I still have to grasp. So, can we start at a metalanguage and there define what "AND" means, for which a formalizable approach is that of truth tables, to establish the atoms of the formal language, from which we then build up the formal system? I remember encountering a minimal logic of $\mathcal{L}=(\neg,\wedge)$, if that is right, can't attribute to the author.

Comment: It's something like that, yes (and it's good to hear that you are reading about natural deduction from Schwichtenberg). Although in actual practice (and this might be nitpicking), I'd say human reasoners are rarely handed a definition of "and"; rather they just imbibe the correct use as very small children, owing I guess to the structure of human brains. As for your other comment: yes, there are probably hundreds of definitions of Boolean algebra, some more succinct than others. This was a kind of mathematical parlor game in late 19th/early 20th centuries (see e.g. old work of Schroeder).

Comment: Thank you, this discussion is not only clarifying but also inspiring! I haven't thought about the use of "and" this deep yet, I'll keep this in mind. Hundreds? I'd hoped to find just a handful, seems to be a long way to properly understand logic, but that's good. We've got a few books by Schroeder at the library, I'll take a peek. Thanks so much!

Comment: Great; thanks for saying so! 'Hundreds' might be exaggerating, but 'dozens' probably isn't. There is an awful lot of lore on this. At some point, you might be interested to read about Peirce's Existential Graphs (if you don't know of them already), which takes the idea of conjoined assertions 'floating in space' pretty seriously.

Comment: "Dozens" sounds rather comprehensible. I've never heard of them, I sure will get something to read about it. I very much appreciate your advice. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Once you select a particular proof system, you should be able to write down a *formal proof* of $(p\land q)\leftrightarrow (q \land p)$. How such a proof will look will vary wildly between different proof systems, though.

For example, in (classical or intuitionistic) sequent calulus, the formal proof might look like this:
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
1) & q \vdash q & \text{axiom} \\
2) & p,q \vdash q & 1, \text{weakening} \\
3) & p \vdash p & \text{axiom} \\
4) & p,q \vdash p & 3, \text{weakening} \\
5) & p,q \vdash q\land p & 2,4,{\land}\mathrm I \\
6) & p\land q \vdash q \land p & 5, {\land}\mathrm E \\
7) & \vdash (p\land q) \to (q\land p) & 6, {\to}\mathrm I \\
8-14) & \vdash (q\land p) \to (p\land q) & \text{(repeat the above with $p$ and $q$ interchanged)} \\
15 & \vdash (p\land q) \leftrightarrow (q\land p) & 7, 14, {\leftrightarrow}I
\end{array}
$$

However, such a proof doesn't really offer any deep insight into how conjunction works. It says more about the proof system than about conjunction, namely that the proof system works "in a sane way" with respect to conjunction.

If you're not interested in proof systems, but in semantics, then you don't get around the fact that truth tables *is the most fundamental way* to define the semantics of the propositional connectives -- much more suitable as a definition than verbal descriptions. Therefore a truth-table based proof *is the most fundamental proof* you can possibly get about semantics here, and everything else will just be more or less convincingly paraphrased guises for the fundamental truth-table based proof.

Comment: Whether truth tables are appropriate depends on the properties of the logic. If you are using classical propositional logic, then the semantics can be described in terms of free Boolean algebras, where finitely generated free Boolean algebras may indeed be effectively described in terms of functions mapping to $\{0, 1\}$. For intuitionistic logic (which is also important), whose semantics is in free Heyting algebras, it's not so simple.